# "Очередь проверок" не отображает количество

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

Не отображаются цифры с количеством проверок ни по одной из тематик.

Скриншот результата:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ранее отображалась цифра, напротив каждого типа проверки.

Comment: [Where are review queue counters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301505/where-are-review-queue-counters)

Comment: @Grundy что с вопросом делать? Удалять? :)

Comment: Наверно подождать, пока его Feeds в чат скинет и сюда не придет специально обученный @alexolut :)

Comment: @Grundy хорошо, подождем специально обученного :)

Comment: @Grundy паршивец! :)

Comment: @DenisBubnov а Вам советую научиться обрезать скриншоты :)

Comment: @alexolut, да лень было, я через `Alt+PrtScn` быстренько сбацал :) я умею ^_^

Comment: Я под виндой юзаю [greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) для этих целей.

Comment: @alexolut жаль, что на Windows скриншоты делаются ни как в MacOs :)

Comment: @alexolut, в винде давно ножницы есть

Comment: @Grundy в какой? Небось такие же как новый сапёр от Майорова, что по 15 минут грузятся.

Comment: @alexolut Nope, [Use Snipping Tool to capture screenshots](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13776/windows-use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots)

Comment: @Grundy странный тул, область расширяет белыми полями зачем-то. Сохранять надо вручную. В общем, встроенные решения всегда достаточно странные.

Comment: @alexolut, можно не сохранять, картинка сразу в буфере обмена

Comment: @Grundy так картинковставлятель для SO не умеет из буфера.

Comment: @alexolut, запили вопрос на мета-мете :-)

Comment: @Grundy я думаю, уже есть

Comment: Может хватит флудить? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Починили и доработали:

> [image: лампочки очередей]

Теперь есть лампочки, показывающие на что нужно обратить внимание в первую очередь.

Подробнее о том, как это должно работать можно почитать на [meta.En.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355233/3240681)

Comment: Не хотите ли самоответить в ["Where are the review queue counters?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301505/340911)?

Comment: @Skyrocker nah, как иногда бывает там говорят. Статус повесили, хватит.

Comment: **Там** говорят? Вроде как раз тут :) ОК, лень, понимаю.